# PHP: Get mysql data from a function as an object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to this so I can't figure out the code to use. I want to get an object from a SQL question so I can get data with $thePerson->FirstName and so on.

I'm calling the function as this:

```
$thePerson = getPerson(1);
```

and this is the function so far:

```
function getPerson ($person) {
    global $con;
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM personal WHERE IDA=?");
    $stmt -> bind_param('i', $person);
    $result = $stmt -> execute();
    $theData = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $stmt -> close();
    return $theData;
}
```

I could really use some help changing the code so it works.

Comment: so whats the problem? have you tried `echo $thePerson->FirstName` yourself?

Comment: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given" is the error from the database select part and then ofc I get "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" if I try "echo $thePerson->FirstName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik `mysql_fetch_object` doesn't work with prepared statements. See [Is it possible to use mysqli_fetch_object with a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976433/is-it-possible-to-use-mysqli-fetch-object-with-a-prepared-statement).

Try to either use `->fetch` on your statement (but use `->bind-result` before).
[Examples on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Or use `->query` instead of your prepare / execute lines, which should return a result set to use with `->fetch_object`.
[Examples on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: Thanks, your links helped me solve this, all I had to do is substitute "$theData = mysqli_fetch_object($result);" with "$theData = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object();"

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ORM: Object Relational Mapper like: http://www.doctrine-project.org/

this is a bit advanced concept, are you sure you need to use this in your project?

Comment: Preferred was object but I'm allowed to supply is at a 2-dimensional array too