# Use method mysqli in php oop

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, fetch

I have a question: Why I can't use method fetch_object() in my script. I have a method:

```
public function magazyn() {
    //return 'magazyn';
    $this->magazyn = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `nazwa`");
    //$this->magazyn->bind_param('ssss', $id, $nazwa, $kategoria, $sn);
    $this->magazyn->execute();
    $this->magazyn->store_result();
    //return $this->magazyn;

    if ($this->magazyn->num_rows > 0) {

        $rows = array();
        while ($row = $this->magazyn->fetch_object()) {
            echo $rows[] = $row;

        }

    } else {
        echo "Brak produktw w bazie";
    }
}
```

The script return error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_stmt::fetch_object() in

But i can use for example "prepare":

```
$this->magazyn = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `nazwa`");
```

Comment: `$poop = $this->magazyn->store_result();` and then  `while ($row = $poop->fetch_object())`

Comment: Basically because the `mysqli_stmt` Object does not have a Method called `fetch_object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `fetch_object` directly on the statement object. As it said here:

[Is it possible to use mysqli_fetch_object with a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976433/is-it-possible-to-use-mysqli-fetch-object-with-a-prepared-statement)

and in the documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

you should get the results and apply the fetch_object to that.

```
/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* now you can fetch the results into an object */
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_object()) {
```