# PHP - prepared statements result as an object

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So, I have the following function:

```
    private function getUserData($user_nickname)
{
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {

        $stmt1=$this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = ?');
        $stmt1->bind_param('s', $user_nickname);
        $stmt1->execute();

        return $stmt1->fetch_object();
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I get the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()

I did a little research and I didn't find any fetch object in mysqli_stmt 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Does it means that if I use prepared statements, I can't use result as an object? I really want it to work as an object.

P.S. I use mysqli.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `$result = $stmt1->get_result(); return $result->fetch_object()` after the `execute` since `fetch_object()` is part of the mysqli_result. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Answer (score 2):

Mysqli is not a very usable API.

You can try to use [get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) but it could be unavailable on your system.

Let me suggest you to use PDO instead of mysqli:

```
private function getUserData($user_nickname)
{
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$user_nickname]);
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Among other benefits over mysqli, PDO can return not only an anonymous `stdObject` but [can create an instance of an existing class](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/objects), passing parameters to constructor. Say, if you have a `User` class, you may write

```
private function getUserData($user_nickname)
{
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$user_nickname]);
    return $stmt->fetchObject('User');
}
```

Comment: Looks like my post has a duplicate and I found the answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976433/is-it-possible-to-use-mysqli-fetch-object-with-a-prepared-statement . And yes, you can use get_result()